# multiplying an array of matrices with a vector

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array of matrices in which I would like to multiply each matrix by a different number. I tried it this way:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> c = np.array([[[1, 2],[3, 4]],[[1, 2],[3, 4]]])
>>> d = np.array([0.1, 0.2])
>>> d*c
array([[[ 0.1,  0.4],
        [ 0.3,  0.8]],

       [[ 0.1,  0.4],
        [ 0.3,  0.8]]])
```

While my intention is to get this result -

```
>>> np.array([d[0]*c[0], d[1]*c[1]])
array([[[ 0.1,  0.2],
        [ 0.3,  0.4]],

       [[ 0.2,  0.4],
        [ 0.6,  0.8]]])
```

What is the NumPy'iest way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an extra couple of axes:

```
In [22]: d[:,None,None] * c
Out[22]: 
array([[[ 0.1,  0.2],
        [ 0.3,  0.4]],

       [[ 0.2,  0.4],
        [ 0.6,  0.8]]])
```

`d[:,None,None]` has shape `(2,1,1)` which is broadcast across your `c` array of shape `(2,2,2)` to multiply each block of `c` by the corresponding element of `d`.

Comment: Is the a difference between this method and `d[:, np.newaxis, np.newaxis]`?

Comment: @Ohm No difference - `np.newaxis is None` returns `True`: `np.newaxis` is just a more explicit synonym for `None`, which in this context means "insert another axis here".

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with normal broadcasting:

```
>>> c*d[:, np.newaxis, np.newaxis]
array([[[ 0.1,  0.2],
    [ 0.3,  0.4]],

   [[ 0.2,  0.4],
    [ 0.6,  0.8]]])
```